# Native vs non-native 1280x720 resolution for video recording

Tags: resolution, external-display

I plug an external monitor to my macbook pro and I need to record training videos at 1280x720 (spec from publisher). I've noticed that with switchres, I can change the resolution to 1280x720.

I've not found a monitor that natively supports 1280x720 according to the specs. Questions:

- Will my recordings be any different? (camtasia)
- Are there any native 1280x720 out there?
- What is the difference betwen a native and non-native support (all the monitor specs I can find don't support 1280x720)?

Comment: In camtasia you can change size of the recording (https://support.techsmith.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003184132-Project-Dimensions-Canvas-Size-). Why do you bother with screen resolution?

Comment: 1280x720 is often listed with its "TV name" of 720p. It's one of the television HD modes, lower than 'full HD' which is 1080p, or 1920x1080. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V52F.png

Comment: I produce production quality video and my editor insists I do full screen on an external monitor. They believe that scaling degrades the quality with camtasia so my concern is what happens to native vs non-native resolution (or even if that matters)